Change FlyoutPage.Detail page on button click via ViewModel
Situation

I've got basic FlyoutPage that has some flyout with menu buttons and main page as details

<FlyoutPage ...>
    <FlyoutPage.Flyout>
        <generalModule:MenuFlyout x:Name="flyoutPage" />
    </FlyoutPage.Flyout>
    <FlyoutPage.Detail>
        <NavigationPage>
            <x:Arguments>
                <local:MainPage />
            </x:Arguments>
        </NavigationPage>
    </FlyoutPage.Detail>
</FlyoutPage>


Buttons in FlyoutPage.Flyout are triggering a command

<ContentPage ...>
<Grid WidthRequest="320" RowDefinitions="Auto,Auto" ColumnDefinitions="*" Margin="5">
    <toolkit:Expander Grid.Row="0">
        <toolkit:Expander.Header>
            <Label Text="MyPages" Style="{StaticResource MenuHeadline}"/>
        </toolkit:Expander.Header>
        <Grid RowDefinitions="Auto,Auto,Auto,Auto" ColumnDefinitions="*" RowSpacing="1">
            <Button Text="Page1" Command="{Binding NavigateToPageCommand}" CommandParameter="Page1" Grid.Row="0" Style="{StaticResource MenuButton}"/>
            <Button Text="Page2" Command="{Binding NavigateToPageCommand}" CommandParameter="Page2" Grid.Row="1" Style="{StaticResource MenuButton}"/>
        </Grid>
    </toolkit:Expander>
</Grid>
</ContentPage>


The command is running method in ViewModel:

    public class ViewModelCommands : ViewModel
    {
        public ViewModelCommands() : base() { }
        public ICommand NavigateToPageCommand { get; private set; }

        public override void Init()
        {
            base.Init();
            NavigateToPageCommand = new Command((page) => NavigateToPage((string)page), (page) => true);
        }
    }



The method in VM is supposed to replace somehow FlyoutPage.Detail

Question
All above bindings work as expected. The question is how shall I change FlyoutPage.Detail... Is it possible with above approach or shall be done in other way?
The VM itself cannot know about Details in Model, so it cannot update/replace it directly.
The method (4) could update some property bound in xaml/code-behind, but I have no idea how (or if it's even possible) to bind to:
    <FlyoutPage.Detail>
        <NavigationPage>
            <x:Arguments>
                <local:MainPage />
            </x:Arguments>
        </NavigationPage>
    </FlyoutPage.Detail>

Plus, it doesn't seem to be a good idea to create NavigationPage in VM and bind to it.
The Clicked method would be in FlyoutPage.Flyout (2) and would have to somehow update Details in FlyoutPage (1), so doesn't seem very appealing. Besides, I would like to stay away from the code-behind as much as possible.
I would like to do it in according to MVVM, but will welcome any working solution.
Summary

I need to change FlyoutPage.Detail on button click
would be best to use commands and stay strict to MVVM if possible
I was wondering about binding it somehow in xaml or code-behind
maybe some direct change from code-behind, but it would involve changing one page's property from second page
maybe there would be a way to somehow return proper page from command and replace it then


Does  the Detail page have its own ViewModel?

Do you want to replace the local:MainPage with another page   or update the property for local:MainPage, by clicking the Button in flyout?

FlyoutPage and FlyoutPage.Flyout have the same VM. FlyoutPage.Detail doesn't have VM as of now, but in the future it will have a different one and it will be changed as I want to completely replace pages in FlyoutPage.Detail.
@LiqunShen-MSFT FlyoutPage and FlyoutPage.Flyout will remain the same and present all the time as a menu of the app. FlyoutPage.Details will be changed frequently as the content/view of the app.

You can directly do it in code behind just as FlyoutPage docs says. Though you could implement Button Command in ViewModel, Flyout.Detail is not bindable. So, you cannot replace the whole page through binding directly in ViewModel.
Let's simplify the Flyout Menu page. Here is a Button named button1 which is used to replace the Detail page.
<Grid WidthRequest="320" RowDefinitions="Auto,Auto" ColumnDefinitions="*" Margin="5">

    <Grid RowDefinitions="Auto,Auto,Auto,Auto" ColumnDefinitions="*" RowSpacing="1">
        <Button x:Name="button1"  x:FieldModifier="public" Text="Page1"  Grid.Row="0" />
     ...
    </Grid>
</Grid>

And in the FlyoutPage code behind, we subscribe the button1's Clicked event to replace the Detail,
public MyFlyoutPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    flyoutPage.button1.Clicked += OnButtonClicked;
    ...      
}

private void OnButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var button = (Button)sender;
    string text = button
    if(text != null)
    {
        if (text == "Page1")
        {
            Detail = new NavigationPage(new MainPage());

        } else
        {
            Detail = new NavigationPage(new NewPage1());
        }
    }
}

And the same goes for more Buttons. For more info, you may refer to FlyoutPage.

I was hoping to get it done omitting the code behind, but anyway, good I am able to do it in any way. Thank you.
